# 16 bit (4 digits) BCD addition (TASM 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, addition, tasm, bcd

I am trying to add two 4 digits (16 bit) BCD numbers and display the result.

I have written the code below but I want to know how do I handle the carry bit because this program is hanging up DosBox (TASM Emulator)

For some reason my professor wanted us to display the input-output , please bear with me :/

```
model small
.data 

 res dw ?
.code
.startup


; 1st number 
mov cx,4
mov bx,0
l1:
    shl bx,4
    mov ah,01
    int 21h

    and al,0FH
    add bl,al
    
loop l1

mov ah,02h   ; display + sign
mov dx,"+"
int 21h


; 2nd number
mov cx,4
mov bx,0
l3:
    shl dx,4
    mov ah,01
    int 21h

    and al,0FH
    add dl,al
loop l3

 mov al,bl
 add al,dl 
 daa
 mov cl,al  # storing lower byte in clower
 mov al,ah
 adc al,bh
 daa 
 mov ch,al  # storing higher byte in c higher
 
 mov [res],cx
 
 mov ax,02h
 mov dx,res  # To display the result
 int 21h




.EXIT
END
```

Also, am I doing something wrong in the code?

Comment: Where you say `mov ax,02h` before "display result" this should be `mov ah,02h` as in the previous usage. Good luck with that though, for displaying a number. MS-DOS doesn't have any number-output function.

Answer (score 0):

For the input of the second number you are resetting the `BX` register and thus are **destroying the first inputted number**! Now the beauty is that you don't need to zero the destination register at all because shifting a word register by 4 bits and doing it 4 times will leave nothing that was written to it in advance. So just drop those initializers.

Your cascaded BCD addition uses the `AH` register but that register **has nothing useful in it** at that point in the program. You should have used the `DH` register instead.

At the end of the addition the `CX` register holds a 4-digit packed BCD. You **can not print that in one go** using the DOS.PrintCharacter function 02h for which the function number goes to `AH` (and not `AX`). You need a loop that iterates over the 4 BCD digits starting at the most significand digit which is stored in the high nibble of the `CH` register.

```
  mov bx, 4
More:
  rol cx, 4        ; Brings highest nibble round to lowest nibble
  mov dl, cl       ; Move to register that DOS expects
  and dl, 15       ; Isolate it
  or  dl, '0'      ; Convert from value [0,9] to character ['0','9']
  mov ah, 02h      ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int 21h
  dec bx
  jnz More
```

#### Putting it all together and writing some better comments

```
  call GetBCD      ; -> DX
  mov  bx, dx

  mov  dl, '+'     ; No need to store this in DX (DH is not used by DOS)
  mov  ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int  21h

  call GetBCD      ; -> DX

  mov al, bl
  add al, dl 
  daa              ; (*) -> CF
  mov cl, al

  mov al, bh
  adc al, dh       ; (*) Picking up the carry from above
  daa 
  mov ch, al
 
  mov bx, 4
More:
  rol cx, 4       ; Brings highest nibble round to lowest nibble
  mov dl, cl      ; Move to register that DOS expects
  and dl, 15      ; Isolate it
  or  dl, '0'     ; Convert from value [0,9] to character ['0','9']
  mov ah, 02h     ; DOS.PrintCharacter
  int 21h
  dec bx
  jnz More

  mov  ax, 4C00h  ; DOS.TerminateProgram
  int  21h

; IN () OUT (dx)
GetBCD:
  push ax
  push cx
  mov  cx, 4
T1:
  mov  ah, 01h    ; DOS.InputCharacter
  int  21h        ; -> AL=['0','9']
  sub  al, '0'    ; -> AL=[0,9]
  shl  dx, 4
  or   dl, al
  loop T1
  pop  cx
  pop  ax
  ret
```